# Combine 2 elements out of a named list in R

Tags: r, list, combinations

I would like to take 2 elements out of a named list, apply a function to it, and put it in a matrix with as row and column name the name of respectively the first and second element that is combined.
For example, I have this named list:

```
input <- list(a="tom", b="dick", c="harry")
```

And as the function to combine the elements, I would use `paste0` The result of the matrix would then be:

```
  a         b           c          
a NA    "tomdick"   "tomharry" 
b NA       NA       "dickharry"         
c NA       NA          NA
```

I have already tried `combn`, but then I get:

```
> combn(input, 2, FUN=function(x) paste0(x[1], x[2]))
[1] "tomdick"   "tomharry"  "dickharry"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe just `outer(input, input, paste0)`? I don't understand why you don't want all the rest of the combinations included in the result- as in your desired result all 3 elements are represented. You haven't explained that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining @David Arenburg's comment with @Jimbou's answer,

```
input <- list(a="tom", b="dick", c="harry")
result <- outer(input, input, paste0)
result[lower.tri(result,diag = T)] <- NA
```

The name result stores the matrix that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a better way. But you can do something like this.

Create an empty dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(input), ncol = length(input)))
colnames(d) <- rownames(d) <- names(input)
d
   a  b  c
a NA NA NA
b NA NA NA
c NA NA NA
```

`for` loop to fill in the names:

```
for(i in row.names(d)){
for(j in colnames(d)){
d[i, j] <- paste0(input[i], input[j])
}}
```

Replace the names in the lower part of the Matrix with NAs

```
d[lower.tri(d, diag = T)] <- NA
d
     a       b         c
a <NA> tomdick  tomharry
b <NA>    <NA> dickharry
c <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
```